# Android bluetooth service name

Tags: android

Is there any way that I can get the service name of the BT discovered device. My bluetooth discovery logis is as follows

```
 startdiscovery()
 {

  boolean status1 = mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

 }

 BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
  {
  if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
        {           


 if(intent.hasExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE))
            {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);      

                            }
                     }
  }
```

Here i know only the "SERVICE NAME" of the discovered device in STRING FORMAT.

bluetoothclass.hasService(int) - This API takes predefined SERVICE NAMES as an input parameter and return TRUE/FALSE. I can use this API as i know only the SERVICE NAME.

Answer (score -1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getBluetoothClass() gives u the class, and then you can extract it from that.

Comment: Thanks for showing the interest. With BluetootClass(), i dont find any element sharing the name of the service offered by the discovered device